# bind to the scroll event of a TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a tinyMCE instance and I would like to know when the user scrolls inside the editor.

I know how to access the active editor and its iframe but so far have been unsuccessful in finding what fires the scroll event.

Seems simply enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using

```
$(editor.getWin()).scroll(function(){
   console.log('fire scroll')
});
```